# Quick question, does $\sin^2(4x) + \cos^2 (4x)$ equal 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Does $\sin^2(4x) + \cos^2 (4x)=1$? So even $\sin^2 (249023049x) + \cos^2 (249023049x) = 1$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does. In fact, for every $x$ you have this identity
$$
\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2=1
$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks Gustavo!

Answer (score 3):

Yes and yes (pretty quick, indeed).

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you again DonAntonio for the quick response!